# How do I implement TikTok LoginKit for iOS without first publishing the app?

Tags: ios, swift, tiktok-api

I'm trying to log users in with TikTok but TikTok requires an App Store URL. I don't have this because I can't finish the app or publish it without using TikTok login. How do I proceed here? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klTEz.png)

I was expecting to be able to test the app without publishing it, but I can't use the LoginKit right now.

Comment: I looked at their docs, it wasn't very clear if that was a requirement... have you been able to contact them?